# Handle bold/text whether in mathmode or not

Tags: math-mode, acro

I use `acro` package in a very large (1000+ pages) document.

For consistency reasons, it happens an acronym is in a formula.

My acro set up

```
\acsetup{
    case-sensitive      = true,
    first-style         = long-short,
    subsequent-style    = long, 
    single-style        = long,
    format/short        = \bfseries,
    format/long         = \bfseries,
    format/first-long   = \bfseries,
    format/foreign      = \itshape,
}
```

I try to handle the cases where an acronym is in `mathmode`.

Indeed `\bfseries` options is bound to generate the error it's not available in `mathmode`.

```
\newcommand{\mymmode}{
\ifmmode \bfseries\boldmath \else \bfseries \fi
}
```

I also try to make sure a long acronym should be in text in mathmode

```
\newcommand{\mymmodeText}{
\ifmmode \mbox \else \fi % <- This looks really bad.
}
```

[image]

M(almost)WE since I get errors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{df}{%
    short = {\text{DF}}, 
    long = {facteur d'actualisation}, 
    tag = {abbrev}, 
    foreign = {Discount Factor}, 
    foreign-babel = {french}, 
    foreign-locale = {english}, 
    plural-form = {facteurs d'actualisation}, 
    sort = {discount}, 
}

\newcommand{\mymmode}{
\ifmmode \bfseries\boldmath \else \bfseries \fi
}

\newcommand{\mymmodeText}{
\ifmmode \mbox \else \fi
}


\acsetup{
    case-sensitive      = true,
    first-style             = long-short,
    subsequent-style    = long, 
    single-style        = long,
    format/short        = \mymmode,
    format/long             = \mymmodeText,
    format/first-long   = \mymmodeText,
    format/foreign      = \itshape,
} 


\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \ac{df}     & = \dots \\
    \acl{df}        & = \dots \\
    \acs{df}        & = \dots \\
    \aclp{df}   & = \dots \\
    \acsp{df}   & = \dots \\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: beware `\newcommand{\mymmode}{` will add a space in text, always use `%` at ends of such lines.  I'd probably use  `\newcommand\mybf[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}}` .. `\mybf{df}` but just using `\textbf{df}` also works in text and math

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the tip on the extra space ! I still miss a piece related to `\acsetup` then.  `format/short` for instance seems to expect a font formatting command like `\bfseries`. How can I make your `\mybf` in that case ?

Comment: just change `short = {\text{DF}}, ` to `short = {\textbf{DF}}, ` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have 500+ acronyms, I try to change the behaviour not in one specific case but directly in `\acsetup`.

Comment: well up to you but that `\text` is making your problem a lot harder to answer, as `\text{DF}` is usable in math but has no supported way to change the font from math, compared with the 2 seconds it would take to change 500 `\text` to `\textbf` in your editor.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK ! so exit the `\acsetup` definition of fonts but rather hardcoding with `\textbf` directly in the acronym definition.

Comment: or better use a custom commad say `\acrofont` and define that to be \textbf, is what I'd do although it's possible the package has some feature for this, I don't know it well

Comment: I'm not sure on the specification here, any and all acronyms may be used in both text and math mode, or is `df` an exceptional acronym that is used (always or sometimes?) in math mode?